# java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '#'

Tags: java

This my code and it throws an exception while formatting the string with use of `String.Format` Java native method.

```
String value = "#%1$s#.*?%#";
String patt = String.format(value);
```

> java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '#'
>
> at java.util.Formatter.checkText(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Formatter.parse(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to do. What did you expect it output? Why?

Comment: Maybe [the documentation for String.format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) would help the OP figure out why his code makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add string format to format the string you want.
Ex :

```
String value = "#%1$s#.*?%#";
String patt = String.format("%s",value);

System.out.println(patt);
```

[Read this](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples)

Answer (score -1):

There are two format methods:

```
public static String format(String format, Object... args)
```

and

```
public static String format(Locale locale, String format, Object... args)
```

locale : specifies the locale to be applied on the format() method.

format : format of the string.

args : arguments for the format string. It may be zero or more

So in your case, whatever format you are specifying is not proper I guess.

You can check different format which you can use over here: https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples

Answer (score -2):

The value:

```
String value = "#%1$s#.*?%#";
```

can't contain the character % . It is used as a reserverd word.

Comment: Yes, it can. In fact, it pretty much has to have a % in it to be any use to the format method.